# how to make popup a modal near the clicked button?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using angularJS with bootstrap, and I'm creating a modal that will show some infos when you click on a button.

As there will be multiple button around the page, I want that this modal pops up near the clicked button, like the modal top-left corner being on top of the button I clicked.
Is this possible? I tried multiple things and the modal always pops up in the middle of the screen.

Current code I'm trying is:

```
    .modal.in {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

.testbox {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

and here the htm page that has the modal content:

```
<div class="testbox">
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title" ng-bind-html="title"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <span ng-bind-html="fullText"></span>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="close()"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried many things in the css but no one seems to be working, I could get something with `position: fixed` but of course only for one button.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at bootstrap popovers - they've already covered this, if I understand you correctly

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/popovers/#popovershow

Answer (score 0):

you might consider using bootstrap popover to do this.
here is an example

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger popover-dismiss" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Dismissible popover</button>`

Comment: is this in newer versions of bootstrap? my project has still bootstrap v3.3.7

Comment: @AJ989 You need to add a `$('[popover]').popover()` to initiate all popovers, otherwise they won't show.

Comment: so I could use popover with a 3.x.x version of bootstrap as well?